# Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I am calling suspended function from onCreate(...)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    ...
    callGetApi()
}
```

and the suspended function is:-

```
suspend fun callGetApi() {....}
```

But the error shows up *Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function*

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> Suspend function should be called only from a coroutine.

That means to call a `suspend` function you need to use a [coroutine builder](https://kt.academy/article/cc-builders), e.g. `launch`, `async` or `runBlocking`(recommended to use only in unit tests). For example:

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    private var job: Job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + job

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        job.cancel()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        launch {
            val result =  callGetApi()
            onResult(result) // onResult is called on the main thread
        }
    }

    suspend fun callGetApi(): String {...}

    fun onResult(result: String) {...}
}
```

To use `Dispatchers.Main` in Android add dependency to the app's `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
```

---

The **MOST RECENT APPROACH** would be to use extension properties in `ViewModel` and `Activity`/`Fragment`:

- In [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) we can use [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) to launch a coroutine:

  ```
  viewModelScope.launch { ... }
  ```

It attached to the lifecycle of `Activity/Fragment` and cancels launched coroutines when they destroyed.

- Similar in `Activity/Fragment` we can use the following extension properties to launch a coroutine:
  [`lifecycleScope.launch {}`](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#lifecyclescope), [`lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {}`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope), [`viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope)(applicable in `Fragments`).

Comment: That's another example of parallel decompostion, but you wrote `async { call() }.await()` and that's an anti-pattern because: 1) there's no concurrency, 2) if `call()` fails, it will cause your top-level `launch`ed coroutine to be immediately cancelled (you get no chance to do regular exception handling), 3) it's more heavyweight than `withContext()`, which reuses the same coroutine.

Comment: Agree, in this case `async-await` would be an abuse.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky please make sure you are implementing `CoroutineScope` interface : `class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope`

Comment: @Sergey  We need `lifecycleScope` api for **launch** in Activity.  And gradle dependency on **androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky not necessary, you can just implement `CoroutineScope` and use `launch` without any errors. Did you implement  `CoroutineScope` and do you still see the error?

Comment: @Sergey Don't pollute Activity with `CoroutineScope` inheritance.  Keep to **S.O.L.I.D.** principles

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky the question was about `callGetApi()` function in Activity. I answered according to that. SOLID principles and architecture patterns are a matter of another question.

Answer (score 44):

Looks like the most elegant way to do it as of **July 2019**, is the one described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOHK_w09pVA&t=410s):

```
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super...

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val result =  callGetApi()
            onResult(result) 
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the correponding lib:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02"
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky well did you add the corresponding lib at the bottom of the answer?

Comment: I am getting a crash

Comment: get error `lifecycleScope Unresolved reference.`

Answer (score 15):

The above answer worked , but i solved it without inheriting `CoroutineScope` class by just using .... 
**gradle.build**

```
  dependencies {
      implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
  }
```

Activity.kt

```
  import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
  import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers

  GlobalScope.launch (Dispatchers.Main) { callGetApi() }
```

`Dispatchers.Main` is important cause you cannot update the UI in any other thread than main.

*But its recommended to inherit CoroutineScope to maintain the lifecycle of the activity and `onDestroy` of the activity to kill the job*

Comment: Yes, this will seem work to for you at first glance, but it goes directly agains the [recommendations in the documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/). Using this style on Android will make your application buggy and cause weird crashes.

Comment: As per docs `GlobalScope.launch` is not recommended to use. The best practice to use local scope to have the possibility to cancel coroutines.

Comment: Will it crash even if i mention the thread .. i.e , `Dispatchers.Main` instead of others like `Dispatchers.Default, Dispatchers.IO, Dispatchers.Unconfined` @MarkoTopolnik  @Sergey

Comment: It's a different source of crash. Your activity may die, but the coroutine will live on. It will then complete later on and try to update the dead activity. `CoroutineScope` is about controlling the lifecycle of a coroutine and making sure it doesn't keep on executing in the background after the receiver of its results is gone.

Comment: This isn't compatible with Kotlin 1.3.60

Comment: And I thought Microrubbishes async/await was twaddle!  Come back OpenVMS ... all is forgiven..