# Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body error

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

So, I'm fairly new to coroutines in kotlin and I don't understand what's going on here. I do have a suspended function called from another one.

What's the right syntax here?

```
suspend fun doSomething(str: Optional<String>) {
  // Error: Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body
  str.map { doSomethingElse() } 
}

suspend fun doSomethingElse() { }
```

whereas, this is fine

```
suspend fun doSomething(str: Optional<String>) {
  if (str.isPresent) {
    doSomethingElse()
  }
}

suspend fun doSomethingElse() {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928668/suspend-function-callgetapi-should-be-called-only-from-a-coroutine-or-another)

Comment: @Sergey I think OP understands what that question is about. The confusion here is about why you seemingly can't call a suspend function from inside another suspend here. It's because the lambda isn't `inline`.

Answer (score 1):

`Optional.map()` is not an inline function. The passed lambda is an interface, so if you try to call a suspend function from the interface, you are no longer calling it from a coroutine.

In this case, you can convert the `Optional<String>` to a nullable `String?` with `.orElse(null)` and then call the function if the result is non-null. `Optional` is Java's solution for null-safety because Java doesn't support it at the syntax/compiler level. You don't need to use it in Kotlin code, unless it is passed to you from Java code.