# Using Kotlin Coroutines Together with Spring Kafka Listeners

Tags: kotlin, spring-kafka, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to mix Spring Kafka (2.5.6.RELEASE) Listeners and Kotlin coroutines. In detail, I have a `suspend fun`:

```
suspend fun updatePrice(command: StockPriceUpdateCommand): Boolean
```

Then, I have a Spring Kafka Listener that must call the function every time it reads a new message from the partition:

```
@KafkaListener(
    id = "priceListener",
    topics = [ "prices" ],
    groupId = "prices",
    properties = [
        "key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
        "value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.DoubleDeserializer"
    ]
 ) 
 fun listenToPrices(
    @Header(name = KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) stock: String,
    @Payload price: Double) {

    useCase.updatePrice(StockPriceUpdateUseCase.StockPriceUpdateCommand(stock, price))
 }
```

Clearly, the compiler doesn't let me call the `updatePrice`, beacuse of the error "*Suspend function 'updatePrice' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function"*.

Which is the right approach in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928668/suspend-function-callgetapi-should-be-called-only-from-a-coroutine-or-another. Basically, you need to launch a coroutine and call `updatePrice` in it.

Comment: Thank you, @Sergey. However, I am in a backend context, not in an Android application. There is Spring that proxy that method. I don't know which could be the side effects of declaring a coroutine :)

Comment: Yes, I noticed, but the coroutine concept is the same: creating a scope (or use existing); launch a coroutine; cancel coroutine when need.

Comment: What if I change my function's signature with the `@KafkaListener` annotation in `suspend fun`?

Comment: I don't familiar with Kafka Listeners, but I guess you will receive the same error for `listenToPrices` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a similar question [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1210) about `@RabbitListener`.

> It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

> My understanding is suspend functions can only be called from a coroutine; since `@RabbitListener` methods are called by the framework, not user code, we'd have to add a shim between the framework and the listener - but exactly how would that perform any useful function?

Comment: Thanks, Gary. So, by now, I have to enclose the code that the listener calls inside a `runBlocking` function. Thanks. I will wait for the native support to `suspend fun` :)