# avoid Error Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, realm, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I want to remove first from db then to do the logout.

But I receive the error:  Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body when calling the logout method

My logout method

```
suspend fun doLogout(token: String) {

    val userId = appService.currentUser?.id

        realm.write {
            var user = query<UserInfo>("_id = $0", userId).first().find()
                user = findLatest(user)!!.also {
                    it.FCMToken.removeAt(productIndex)
                }
                copyToRealm(user)


                appService.currentUser?.logOut() // Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body

            
        }
}
```

Any easy way to solve this?
I want first to remove from db then do the logOut().

I want first to remove from db then do the logOut().

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928862/1731626

Comment: This is not the same question, please remove that, I ve tried the examples and still not working

Comment: Have you tried to call the suspend function within a coroutine? Please give an example, update the question, and I will revise.