# Android kotlin suspend function 'getInfo' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am getting the following error:

```
suspend function 'getInfo' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```java
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.myapp.test.WakeLocker.acquire
import com.myapp.test.WakeLocker.release
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

class WidgetService : BroadcastReceiver() {
    var json = JSONObject()
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        //wake the device
        acquire(context)

        //increase the number in the widget
        val preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0)
        val urlCode = preferences.getString("urlCode", "")
        Log.d("WidgetService1", urlCode!!)
        if (urlCode != "") {
            val getPack = GetPack(urlCode)
            json = try {
                getPack.getInfo()
            } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString("json", json.toString())
            editor.apply()
        }

        //force widget update
        val widgetIntent = Intent(context, MyWidget::class.java)
        widgetIntent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
        val ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            .getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, MyWidget::class.java))
        widgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids)
        context.sendBroadcast(widgetIntent)
        Log.d("WidgetService", "Widget set to update!")

        //go back to sleep
        release()
    }
}
```

```java
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import java.io.IOException

class GetPack(id: String) {
    private val baseURL = "http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    private val finalURL = "$baseURL:8080"

    suspend fun getInfo(): JSONObject = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val json = JSONObject()
        try {
            val document = Jsoup.connect(finalURL).get()
            val steps = JSONArray()
            val elements = document.select("#progressTracker-container > div")
            for (ele in elements) {
                val item = JSONObject()
                val reached = ele.attr("data-reached") == "reached"
                val message = ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage").first().ownText()
                val data = ele.select(".milestone-primaryMessage > .nowrap").text()
                item.put("reached", reached)
                item.put("message", message)
                item.put("data", data)
                steps.put(item)
            }
            val primaryStatus = document.getElementById("primaryStatus")
            json.put("status", primaryStatus.text())
            json.put("steps", steps)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
        json
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suspend function 'callGetApi' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928668/suspend-function-callgetapi-should-be-called-only-from-a-coroutine-or-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `suspend fun getInfo()` from `GetPack` class is mentioned with `suspend`. In Kotlin, suspend functions should be either called from suspend function or from Coroutines.

More regarding Coroutines: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv

**Answer:**

You can either do one of the following to resolve this error:

1. Remove `suspend` from `getInfo()` and make it simple `fun getInfo()`. But my suggestion is don't do this as we are doing Json parsing here which might take time.
2. Instead, in the `WidgetService` class you can start Coroutine with IO dispatcher as follow:

```
1. Add implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0' in app build gradle. 
2. Use lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {} as follow

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val getPack = GetPack(urlCode)
            json = try {
                getPack.getInfo()
            } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                throw RuntimeException(e)
            }
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString("json", json.toString())
            editor.apply()
        }
```

Comment: Ok, but: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhsHF.png

Comment: Ohh. You can then use `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { //remaining code as it is}`.

But the best practice is use a scope which is lifecycle aware hence here you can do as follow:
1. Add `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'` in app build gradle.
2. Use lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {//remaining code as it is }

Comment: Can you edit the answer so that it doesn't bother me.

Comment: Edited in above answer for fullfillness.

Comment: How should I declare the variable, it doesn't let me import any library. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKjuU.png

Comment: Does not need to create a variable you have to just add `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'`  in `app build gradle` under `dependencies {}` section. Once you do this,  you can directly use `lifecycleScope` in any Activity or Fragment.
`

Comment: Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McUb7.png

Comment: But it gives me error when I put it in the code, it tells me to declare the variable.